# Route to an object by id of related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Hej folks,

I'm currently completely stuck with the following and don't even have the slightest idea how to proceed, so any help with my Rails 3(.1)-app would be appreciated:

I have a "document_type" which can 'have many' (versions of) "documents", that can be accessed by a short URL which reads like `domain.com/d<id of form>` - like `domain.com/d12` for the document with the id 12. Nothing special so far. But now I was asked to change (or more precisely add) a routing that allows access via the id of the document_type and the document's id: `domain.com/t2v3` (or something alike), with "2" being the document_type_id and "3" as the document's version (both o/c in the documents-table).

The code for what I've got (just in case...) is:

`match 'd:id', :controller => 'documents', :action => 'show', :id => 'id'`

I just can't figure out how (or even if...) this could be done...

tyia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of the url is flexible, I'd change it: domain.com/t2/v3

Then your route would look like:

```
get 't:type_id/v:version_id', :to => 'documents#show_version'
```

Comment: sadly it isn't (at least no additional "/" shall be used) :-/

Comment: ...I'll accept this solution, as it's how I ended up doing it- even though it's not totally what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

tAnother approach could be to keep your route as simple as possible :

```
get ':id', :controller => 'documents', :action => 'show'
```

Then you may use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to replace the default integer identifier with a "friendly" one.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :doc_id, :use => :slugged

  def doc_id
    "t#{id}v#{version}"
  end
end
```

More about this useful gem here : http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/Guide.rdoc

Comment: interesting- I'll give it a shot (...soon... priority has been lowered ;-)). Thanks!